How to achieve this scenario on SQL/SparkSQL/PySpark in Databricks
I have a delta table named "test_table" in databricks like:
data_value,batch_number,rnumber,file_name,responseStatus,url
21gdsddnh,1,1,subject_1.csv,'','',''
21gdsdernh,1,2,subject_1.csv,'','',''
21gdweddnh,1,3,subject_1.csv,'','',''
21gdweddnh,2,1,subject_2.csv,'','',''
21gdweddnh,2,2,subject_2.csv,'','',''
21gdweddnh,2,3,subject_2.csv,'','',''

Now a csv file named "response.csv" like:
file_name,responseStatus,url
subject_1.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
subject_1.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
subject_1.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
subject_2.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
subject_2.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
subject_2.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com

Requirement: I need to attach/Update test_table such that these 6 rows of "response.csv" get attached to  "test_table" so that my test_table finally looks like:
data_value,batch_number,rnumber,file_name,responseStatus,url
21gdsddnh,1,1,subject_1.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
21gdsdernh,1,2,subject_1.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
21gdweddnh,1,3,subject_1.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
21gdweddnh,2,1,subject_2.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
21gdweddnh,2,2,subject_2.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
21gdweddnh,2,3,subject_2.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com


So what are you asking? You've told us what you need to do, but you've not asked anything. [so] isn't free coding service. Explain the difficulty you are having solving the problem. Demonstrate your attempts and tell us why they aren't working.

Will the csv always have the same responseStatus and url for a given file_name? Say you have - {subject_1.csv,SUCCESS,/org/source/restapi.com
subject_1.csv,FAILED,/org/source/restapi.com} . What do you update the target table with? You need to have some key which is unique so the update isn't ambiguous.

If it's guaranteed that the number of rows in both tables is the same and they are sorted in the same order then you can just apply the row_number window function over both dataframes and then join them.
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

df_l = spark_session.read.format('delta').load('test_table')
df_r = spark_session.read.csv('response.csv', header=True)

w = Window.orderBy('file_name')

df_l = df_l.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w))
df_r = df_r.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w))

df_res = df_l.join(df_r, 'rn')
df_res = df_res.select('data_value', 'batch_number', 'rnumber', df_l['file_name'], df_r['responseStatus'], df_r['url'])

df_res.show()

# +----------+------------+-------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
# |data_value|batch_number|rnumber|    file_name|responseStatus|                 url|
# +----------+------------+-------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
# | 21gdsddnh|           1|      1|subject_1.csv|       SUCCESS|/org/source/resta...|
# |21gdsdernh|           1|      2|subject_1.csv|       SUCCESS|/org/source/resta...|
# |21gdweddnh|           1|      3|subject_1.csv|       SUCCESS|/org/source/resta...|
# |21gdweddnh|           2|      1|subject_2.csv|       SUCCESS|/org/source/resta...|
# |21gdweddnh|           2|      2|subject_2.csv|       SUCCESS|/org/source/resta...|
# |21gdweddnh|           2|      3|subject_2.csv|       SUCCESS|/org/source/resta...|
# +----------+------------+-------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+


OP, while this answer isn't wrong and does answer the question as posed ... strong word of caution that that ordering and cardinality assumption is wishful. Probably safer to assume for all intents and purposes ordering by anything non-unique is random.

it's not wishful, it's explicitly stated that both tables must be consistent for the code to work. Whether it's guaranteed by the nature of the data or by some sort of processing before applying.

It's extremely wishful. Happy to be proven wrong if you can find any documentation which supports some delta table properties guaranteeing a non-unique ordering to be reliably deterministic. Even on the csv reader side I'm skeptical the line order of the file will be preserved after ordering on file_name. Like I said, this answer isn't wrong but I'm wary that assumption can realistically ever be true.

And just for politeness, I'm not criticizing your answer. Just have a hunch that OP is a beginner and that they should proceed with a lot of caution with that assumption rather than copy/pasting because it might work fine on a small sample, for example if everything is on a single partition.

@busfighter think like  test_table is an existing table on production database.So when I get a 6 record dataframe , how I need to attach that to existing test_table . That's why I mentioned , how to UPDATE existing test_table with that CSV data. If I do like df.write.mode(overwrite/append) it's not correct right.
